# Why does my Navbar push my overall content aside?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 sections. One is a Navbar, second is a div which is the bg, basically a striped background, third is my content within the div (headers, info boxes etc)

when I place my navbar, it pushes all of my content to the right since it is a new div, cannot figure out how to fix it,

Usually this is an easy fix, maybe I am having a rough day and cannot figure out a simple piece of code. Could somebody elaborateon what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <div class="stripes">
        <span></span>
        <span></span> 
        <span></span> 
        <span></span> 
    </div>

<section id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-content">
           <div class="header-header">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>    
           </div>
            <div class="header-info">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae assumenda quas tempora totam qui soluta illum dolorem impedit ad, ratione, aspernatur ipsa placeat adipisci molestias id tenetur natus voluptates quis.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

SASS

```
$mainBlue: #3CB6FD
$secondBlue: #4A5AFC

html
    height: 100% !important
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important

.gridContainer
    display: grid
    grid-template-columns: 100%
    grid-template-areas: "header"

header
    position: relative !important
    display: flex !important

#header
    position: relative
    z-index: 3
    height: 780px
    grid-area: header
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center
    display: flex

.nav
    position: relative
    z-index: 999
    height: auto

    ul
        list-style-type: none

        li
            display: inline-block

            a
                color: white
                text-decoration: none
                display: block
                padding: 1em


.header-content
    margin: 0 auto
    max-width: 60%

.phone-container
    position: absolute
    bottom: 0
    right: 0
    height: 100%
    width: 30%
    display: block
    transform: rotate(-10deg)

.phone
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    display: block
    background: url(../img/phone.png)
    background-size: contain
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    z-index: 6

.container
    width: 950px
    margin: 0 auto

header .stripes
    background: linear-gradient(to left, $mainBlue , $secondBlue)
    display: block
    height: 100%
    position: absolute
    transform: skewY(-12deg)
    width: 100%
    overflow: hidden
    transform-origin: 0

span
    display: block
    position: absolute
    &:first-child
        background: linear-gradient(to left, $mainBlue , $secondBlue)
        top: 0
        left: 0
        width: 40%
        height: 200px
    &:nth-child(2)
        background: linear-gradient(to left, $mainBlue , $secondBlue)
        bottom: 0
        height: 200px
        width: 50%
        z-index: 2
    &:nth-child(3)
        background: linear-gradient(to left, $mainBlue , $secondBlue)
        bottom: 200px
        height: 130px
        width: 33%
    &:nth-child(4)
        background: linear-gradient(to left, $mainBlue , $secondBlue)
        right: 0
        height: 230px
        width: 53%
        bottom: 0

.header-header
    margin-bottom: 30px

h1
    font-size: 3em
    font-weight: 700
    color: white

p
    font-size: 1em
    font-weight: 400
    color: white
    line-height: 2
```

Comment: Since the HTML and CSS are long enough it'd be nice if you could create a working snippet. Also, your HTML has a closing `</header>` tag that it's not opened before, so we don't don't exactly what's going on here. (Same for `html` and `body`, but they're less important to the question)

Comment: https://codepen.io/donnieberry97/pen/vrgmMZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why have you used `display: flex !important` in your `header`?
remove that and your content will be back to normal. And if you want the stripes to move up then you can use `top: -10px` in your `header .stripes` class

demo: https://codepen.io/nlshnk95/pen/mKRwMK